# How to clean fireplace grout?

Tags: cleaning, fireplace, grout

Please see the attached photos. I'm not sure what is even in the grout but it appears stained green-brown with mildew maybe? I used an electric power drill grout brush attachment (see picture) with vinegar to no avail. Do I need to go out and buy a dremel?

[image: fireplace]

[image: closeup]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using comet or bleach ?

Comment: I have even been able to use a paste made from baking soda and water to scrub things such as built up brake dust and corrosion.